# R: Return value of grep is...?

Tags: r, regex

all. I've posted a few times in the past few days. Thanks for all your help...I'm starting to figure some of this out.

I am using grep with value=TRUE to generate a list of elements in a character vector that match a set of patterns separated by the "|" operator. I would like to use the output of this comparison to update a list of checkboxes in a shiny app to reflect all the matches. i am using updateCheckBoxGroupInput to do this.

The problem I am having is with the return value of grep.

with the following code...

```
    customersWithOrders <- orderData %>%
                           filter(grepl(paste(input$product_selection, collapse = "|"), ITM_DESC)) 
                           %>% select(customer)
                           %>% distinct(customer)        
    customerMatches <- grep(paste(out, collapse = "|"), customersWithOrders, ignore.case = TRUE, 
                       value=TRUE)
    updatePrettyCheckboxGroup(session
                              , "customer_selection"
                              , choices = customerMatches
                              , selected = customerMatches)
```

...the updated list of checkboxes is one checkbox named "customer" which is the column name from the orderData DF.

if I modify the code as below...

```
   customersWithOrders <- orderData %>%
                           filter(grepl(paste(input$product_selection, collapse = "|"), ITM_DESC)) 
                           %>% select(customer)
                           %>% distinct(customer)        
    customerMatches <- grep(paste(out, collapse = "|"), customersWithOrders, ignore.case = TRUE, 
                       value=TRUE)
    updatePrettyCheckboxGroup(session
                              , "customer_selection"
                              , choices = **paste**(customerMatches)
                              , selected = **paste**(customerMatches))
```

the updated checkbox list is one checkbox named c(/"customer1/", /"customer2/", etc)

this...

```
    class(customerMatches)
```

shows that it is a character vector but, I cannot figure out how to get each element to be an individual checkbox in the updateCheckBoxGroupInput function.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try with `customerMatches  <- grep(paste(out, collapse = "|"), customersWithOrders$customer, ignore.case = TRUE, value=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @ronak shah for the answer. Thanks!

> Can you try with
>
> ```
> customerMatches <- grep(paste(out, collapse = "|"), customersWithOrders$customer, ignore.case = TRUE, value=TRUE)
> ```
>
> – Ronak Shah 12 hours ago